# Lightbox type effect to support a HTML/jQuery image map

Tags: plugin-recommendation, jquery, images, html, map

I haven't used WP extensively before but I'm more experienced in HTML/jQuery and I'm helping a friend with their existing WP blog.

I have designed an interactive map menu using the technique described here: [tutorial](http://www.workwithchoicecuts.com/methodology/revisiting-the-html-image-map/) and [demo](http://www.workwithchoicecuts.com/demo/html-image-map-revisted/index.htm) (essentially each region of the map has it's own image for both selected and non-selected states and an image map and jQuery is used to toggle the selection of each area)

What I want to achieve is to have this pop up in a lightbox style box when you go to the blog homepage, and then the areas selected on the map dictate the categories of posts that are displayed.

I had created this using plain HTML and jQuery (without a lightbox type plugin - just doing the fade manually) but now I need to integrate it with their website - although I imagine I may have to code this completely differently for WP.

So my main questions are:

1. Is there a lightbox type WP plugin that supports all of the content I need (HTML image map and a few other buttons and options)?
2. Would the most appropriate plugin then support the jQuery method I have used from the tutorial above or is there a better way of achieving this?
3. How can I get this to automatically popup for the homepage of the blog?

I hope I've included enough information, if you have any questions just let me know.

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 1):

I use [Easy Fancybox](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/easy-fancybox/). It has a number of great features that allows for auto-detection of image files, and fancybox allows for HTML or inline, which is what you are looking for.

It also allows for it to automatically popup, just attached the `fancybox-auto` class

Comment: That;s great thanks I'll look into it. Do you have any idea if it's easily customisable to remove the X in the corner and use buttons within the box instead?

Comment: Sorry nevermind I found the option for it :) 

Without having much knowledge of Wordpress, do you know how I'd go about combining image map within the fancybox with some custom jQuery to trigger events based on the area clicks?